# Calculating average: Converting Double to String Error

Tags: java, average

I just can't get my code right how I want to. (Java Beginner)

So the way it should work is this:
When running the program I want to get a window and fill in a number(X) how large(Z) the array should be. Next I get X windows where I have to type in the numbers I want to put in the array. Finally the program should calculate the sum of all numbers and divide by the size(Z) of the array, to get the average of all numbers in the array.

I'm almost finished but all I get are errors regarding Double to String conversion. I tried everything I know out but couldn't make it work. Please excuse there may be spelling mistakes, I had to translate it to english.

Error: 
Below //*Initialization* *and* *Output* line, either it's 'void' type not allowed here or incompatible types: void cannot be converted to String

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Aufgabe42
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Declare variable
        String input, output, requestNumber;
        double[] arrayNumber;
        int size;

        //Input
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type in the size of the array.");

        //Variable Initialization
        size = Integer.parseInt(input);
        arrayNumbers = new double[size];

        //Request numbers
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            requestNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Tell me a number:");
            arrayNumber[i] = Double.parseDouble(requestNumber);
        }

        String returnAverage;

        //Initialization and Output
        output = Double.toString(JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Average is: " + getAverage(arrayNumber)));
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static double getAverage(double[] arrayNumber)
    {
        //Declare variable

        double arraySum,average;

        //Initialization
        arraySum = 0;



        returnAverage = Double.toString(average);

        //Sum array values
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayZNumber.length; i++)
        {
            arraySum += arrayNumber[i];
        }

        //Calculate Average
        average = arraySum / arrayNumber.length;

        return  average;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error you're getting and to indicate which line of your code is causing it.

Comment: I have like 5 versions of the code now. But it always tells me the err is in the //Initialization and Output line, either it's *'void' type not allowed here* or  *incompatible types: void cannot be converted to String*

Comment: The return type of `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` is `void`: it does not return _anything_.  You cannot use it as an argument to `Double.toString()`.  Why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: That was recommend by someone on a forum post I have read so I tried this out. I also tried out to convert it like this 'variable = Double.toString(variableOne);' So how can I convert it?

Comment: There's no point in assigning something to `output` immediately before exiting the program.  If the last thing you want to do is pop up a dialog to display your result, then just write `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average is: ",...);". `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog' returns **nothing**; there's nothing to "convert".

Comment: Oh I understand now. So I just write 'JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Average is: " + getAverage(arrayNumber));' and that's it., right? As far as I see now it works. But can you tell me why I do not have to convert this 'average' from a Double to a String?

Answer (score 1):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()
```

Has a void return type. You either want

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog()
```

Or to remove

```
Double output = Double.valueOf(JOptionPane.showMessageDialog...)
```

near the end

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html